# Angular ng-repeat in table to iterate over key with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, smart-table

I am using Angular with Smart-Table to iterate through a nested array of objects to fill a table. I am able to get some of the values out easily, but others have proved difficult. In the sample data below, you'll see that the keys `voucherNumber`, `vendor`, `description`, and `amount` are attached to array values. They are related in such a way that `voucherNumber[0]`, `vendor[0]`, `description[0]`, and `amount[0]` all refer to the same document.

Currently, my code below shows `period`, `uploadDate`, and `transferCode` correctly. The rest it just shows arrays (for example, under `voucherNumber` are two table cells, one containing `["34", "22"]` and the other `["12", "32"]`.

I know the structure of this model is a bit convoluted, and I intend to simplify it a bit at a later point. Is there any way I can work with ng-repeat to get it to display properly in my table for the time being?

```
//Sample Code
[{
    "period": 4,
    "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
    "section":[{
      "transferCode": 8675309,
      "details": [
        {
          "voucherNumber": ["34", "22"],
          "vendor": ["jimmy", "jonny"],
          "description": ["blah", "blah2"],
          "amount": [45555, 3421]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "period": 4,
    "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
    "section":[{
      "transferCode": 45576543,
      "details": [
        {
          "voucherNumber": ["12", "32"],
          "vendor": ["jane", "sarah"],
          "description": ["eep", "orp"],
          "amount": [97864, 23214]
        }
      ]
    }]

  }]

//HTML and Angular

<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="TransferController as transfers">

    <table st-table="transfers" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th st-sort="period">Period</th>
          <th st-sort="uploadDate">Upload Date</th>
          <th st-sort="uploadDate">Transfer Code</th>
          <th st-sort="vendor">Vendor</th>
          <th st-sort="description">Description</th>
          <th st-sort="amount">Amount (SSP)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">
            <input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
          <th>
            <input st-search="period" placeholder="search by period" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input st-search="uploadDate" placeholder="search by upload date" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th> 
          <th>
            <input st-search="transferCode" placeholder="search by transfer code" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input st-search="vendor" placeholder="search by vendor" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input st-search="description" placeholder="search by description" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input st-search="amount" placeholder="search by amount" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="toplevel in transfers.all">
        <tr ng-repeat="code in toplevel.section">
          <td>{{ toplevel.period }}</td>
          <td>{{ toplevel.uploadDate | date }}</td>
          <td>{{ code.transferCode }}</td>
          <td  ng-repeat="detail in code.details">{{ detail.amount }}</td>
          <td  ng-repeat="detail in code.details">{{ detail.description }}</td>
          <td  ng-repeat="detail in code.details">{{ detail.amount }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you write a function which converts this json into another json which is more displayable... in case you want to continue with the current structure you will have to use nested ng-repeat.. first one for outer array, inner one for details

Comment: This structure isn't going to work in conjunction with smart-table if you expect `st-search` to work or column sorts. You can map it to a more friendly structure when you receive it

Comment: well, that's a bummer. I guess I'll have to write that function sooner than I though. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you see it a touch better: https://jsfiddle.net/92wqs2sh/1/

The concept is the same and I'm fairly certain you can replace the `div` elements with the appropriate `td` elements without too much fuss.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately @charlietfl is correct; I need to restructure my data if I want the search/sort/filter functions of Smart Table to work. Once I have the data restructured it should be easy to put in the table. Your solution works well though!

Answer (score 0):

you can change:

```
<td  ng-repeat="detail in code.details">{{ detail.amount }}</td>
```

to

```
<td  ng-repeat="detail in code.details">
       <span ng-repeat="amount in detail.amount">{{ amount }}</span>
</td>
```